# Looking for basic Node.js caching solution

Tags: node.js, caching

My goals are to:

- be able to set an item by key
- be able to retrieve the item by key
- set an expiration on each item
- be able to invoke a callback upon expiration to refresh it.

Is there any JavaScript library that can do all that?

Comment: Redis would be perfect for your use case.  And, there are many client libraries available for Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on whether you'd like to do server side or client side caching.  You could likely use the NPM node-cache module.  If you're looking for a more detailed walk through on how to cache, take a look at this URL at scotch.io (https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-optimize-node-requests-with-simple-caching-strategies).  That example uses Express and memory-cache.  Hope this helps!